# Read all items of DynamoDB table

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to read all items of a DynamoDb table. I am using the table.scan() function. It is giving me the response. But, the output is arranged in a haphazard way. 
I am supposed to get output like this -

```
{
"Items": [
{
  "Name": "ABC",
  "Location": "sdkjc",
  "id": "abc"
},

{
  "Name": "DEF",
  "Location": "jfyef",
  "id": "def"
}
]
}
```

But I am getting -

```
{
"Items": [
{
  "Name": "ABC",
  },
  {
  "Location": "sdkjc",
  "id": "abc"
  },

  {
  "Name": "DEF",
  "Location": "jfyef",
  },
  {
  "id": "def"
}
]
}
```

Code -

```
 import boto3
 dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
 table = dynamodb.Table(event['tableName'])
 response = table.scan()
 print (response)
```

There is no pattern in the output. What can be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the data is stored in the pattern you expect? DynamoDB does not have any limitations on how structure the data in an item.

Comment: most probably u have stored the data in that way.

Comment: @kaskelotti  Data is stored in the pattern I mentioned.

Comment: @rohitwtbs Data is stored in the pattern I mentioned.

Comment: @TeeKay can you show the code for inserting data in dynamoDB.

Comment: @rohitwtbs I have created table manually with these three columns.

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
def read():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    table = dynamodb.Table("test")
    items = table.scan()['Items']
    for item in items:
        print (item)
```

Comment: This will print the items we get from dynamodb. It is printing the way I have mentioned in the question. No particular pattern.